# how to use Flask Jinja2 url_for with multiple parameters

Tags: python, flask

I have a problem while using `jinja2` `url_for()` function.

I have a route like this:

```
@app.route('/article/<int:article_id>/<url_title>/', methods=['GET'])
def article_page(article_id, url_title):
    article = Article.query.get(article_id)
    if article == None:
        abort(404)
    return render_template('article.html', article=article)
```

in jinja template file,i want to create a url which links to article_page,so i write like this:

```
<h5>
  <a href="{{ url_for('article_page',article_id=article.id,url_title=article.url_title) }}">{{ article.title }}</a>
</h5>
```

but when I run this page, I get a error:

```
raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method)
BuildError: ('article_page', {'article_id': 1}, None)
```

It seems like that the second parameter `url_title` missing.
How can I use `url_for()` with multiple parameters correctly?

Comment: This happens if `article.url_title` is `None`. Make sure it's not `None`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [`url_for` documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.url_for):

> If the value of a query argument is None, the whole pair is skipped.

Make sure that `url_title` is not `None`.

Or specify default value for `url_title` in the `article_page` function.

Answer (score 8):

You missed a dot, try that:

```
url_for('.article_page', article_id=article.id, url_title=article.url_title)
```