# python/flask Build Error with url_for, extra None

Tags: python, flask

I cannot figure out where the extra `None` is coming from.  I've tried these links to no avail:  [Build error with variables and url_for in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023488/build-error-with-variables-and-url-for-in-flask?rq=1)
[how to use Flask Jinja2 url_for with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810630/how-to-use-flask-jinja2-url-for-with-multiple-parameters)

Also, I am **not** using `BluePrint`.

Here is my users.html template:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('user_page', user_id=user.user_id) }}"> {{ user.name }} </a>
```

Here are two different `user.py` files I've tried:

```
@app.route('/user')
def user_page():
    args = show_user_parser.parse_args()
    user_id = args['user_id']
    return page_for_user(user_id)

@app.route('/user/<user_id>')
def user_page(user_id):
    return page_for_user(user_id)

def page_for_user(user_id):
   try:
       cur.execute(list_user_detailed_query, (user_id,))
   except psycopg2.OperationalError:
       return render_template('error.html')
   except psycopg2.IntegrityError:
       connection.rollback()
       return render_template('error.html')
   data = cur.fetchone()
   return render_template('user.html',
                          name=data['name'],
                          email=data['email'],
                          undergrad=data['undergrad'],
                          cv=data['cv'])
```

Here is the build error:

```
BuildError: ('user_page', {'user_id': '1'}, None)
```

Comment: what does this page_for_user() function do ? Can you show the code for it ?

Comment: added code, although it's probably not relevant since manually entering the /user/id or /user?user_id=... was working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You've named both your routes "user_page", so I bet the first one (which takes no arguments) is winning and when you try to construct a url with arguments it fails. Rename the functions so they're different and that should fix it.

Comment: I showed both code snippets, but both are not actually registered simultaneously.  I would comment out one def user_page: when running my server.